# Partial Display of Unicode Characters in cmd.exe from java, no characters from shell commands

Tags: java, unicode, cmd

I am experiencing some issues with java Unicode output. I've tried multiple things and I know see the Unicode characters, but they are preceded by a diamond with a question mark inside.

Here is my test file created with notepad:
[image: saving the file]
[image: file contents]

Here is the file working in notepad++:
[image: sreenshot of file in notepad++ showing unicode]

Here is my cmd.exe output:
[image]

cmd font settings:
[image: showing my cmd.exe settngs for font]

Run `cmd /U`, still no characters (found different font was used here [Consolas] which is why its question marks in boxes):
[image]

Windows version:
[image: screenshot from winver]

---

I tried powershell as well, which seems to think its a different encoding:
[image: powershell output trying to type the file]

---

I wrote a small java program, and that is able to print the Unicode, but it some cases with an extra character preceding it.

```java
public class App {

  private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Charset utf8Charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    Charset defaultCharset = Charset.defaultCharset();

    System.out.println(defaultCharset);

    System.out.println("A ");
    System.out.println("B ✔ ");
    System.out.println("C ❌");     
  }
}
```

I then run this java app  with the following flag

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

here is the output:
[image]

---

Why can my Java app print Unicode but not the cmd.exe directly?

How is java adding in characters cmd.exe doesn't know about?

What else can I test/try/change to get Unicode to behave better.

---

Notes:

- I read the Lucida Console should work; I tried all fonts in the field, `NSimSun` showed the x and checkmark, but not the emoji face. This font is a bit hard on my eyes though.
- When I opened the txt file in Word, if I selected all the text and set it to Consolas or Lucida Console it seemed to change the emojis to Segoe UI, so maybe the font's just don't support it - though I've seen other posts which suggest Lucida Console should work?

Comment: If you run 'charmap', set the font to Lucida Console, you'll see what characters it does or does not have.

Comment: **1st**  Use `type -Encoding UTF8 -Path .\emoji-test.txt` in PowerShell. **2nd** Proper display of characters depends both on the font and the rendering software (engine) used. Run your java from *Command prompt* tab in *Windows Terminal* (`wt.exe`)  instead of pure `cmd`. The [Cascadia Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/terminal/cascadia-code) font should cover your needs inside WT but doesn't in pure `cmd`…